# $animate.addClass TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

For my directive I'm trying to use the animate service:

```
$animate.addClass(clickedCard, "translate-to-player-spot-1", function () {
    alert('wooo!');
});
```

<strike>But this fires the alert right away and the animation isn't taking place! I need to perform functions at the end of the animations.</strike>

**Update** I changed the Angular version to 1.3.6 and now get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at http://192.168.0.102/CardGame/js/angular-animate.min.js:20:254
    at http://192.168.0.102/CardGame/js/angular-animate.min.js:8:69
    at k.$digest (http://192.168.0.102/CardGame/js/angular.min.js:124:43)
    at k.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1468:23)
    at k.$apply (http://192.168.0.102/CardGame/js/angular.min.js:126:58)
    at k.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1478:22)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:797:25)
    at HTMLDivElement.c (http://192.168.0.102/CardGame/js/angular.min.js:32:285)
```

The CSS looks like:

```
.translate-to-player-spot-1 {
    transform: translate(0px,-270px);
    transition: transform 50s linear;
}
```

If I add `ng-class="card.moveTo"` to the HTML and set in the directive:

```
clickedCard.moveTo = 'translate-to-player-spot-1'
```

Then it does actually go through the animation and all kinds of angular classes get added:

```
ng-animate translate-to-player-spot-1-add translate-to-player-spot-1 translate-to-player-spot-1-add-active
```

I have a feeling I'm not understanding the animation in AngularJS - can someone please shed some light?

Thanks!

The HTML:

```
<div id="{{card.id}}" ng-class="card.moveTo" class="card-wrap card-art card-art-{{card.back}} ready-to-move-{{card.readyToMove}}" ng-click="click()" ng-repeat="card in cardsCtrl.cards">
    <div ng-class="card.name" class="card-art">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant directive:

```
app.directive('playerHandTemplate', function(PlayerHand, PlayerPlayed) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/card.html',
        scope:{},
        link: function(scope, element, $animate) {
            element.on('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'translate-to-player-spot-1');
            })});
        },
        controller: function($scope, $animate) {
            this.cards = PlayerHand.getHand();

            $scope.click = function() {
                var clickedCard = this.card;

                if (clickedCard.readyToMove === true) {
                    $animate.addClass(clickedCard, "translate-to-player-spot-1", function () {
                        alert('wooo!');
                    });
                } else {
                     PlayerHand.changeReadyToMove(clickedCard);
                }

            }

        },
        controllerAs: 'cardsCtrl'
    };
});
```

PlayerHand is a service and getHand() just returns an array of objects.

Comment: What is `clickedCard` in the first example? The first argument passed to `addClass` should be a DOM element.

Comment: @tasseKATT I checked the version and updated to the most recent so its at 1.3.6 but now I'm getting a different error.

clickedCard is an object in an array. I'll add more code to make it clearer but when you say DOM element I assume you mean what the DOM element is bound to right? I though in Angular i wasn't supposed to modify DOM elements directly.

Comment: No, I mean a DOM element. There are times where you have to deal with the DOM directly, and using the `$animate` service is one of them. And when you have to do it, do it from a directive. Where is the directive placed, on a parent element to the div with ng-repeat?

Comment: @tasseKATT I've added the full directive to the code, from my reading I think I'm supposed to use link instead of controller for the animation something like:

            `link: function(scope, element, $animate) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        $animate.addClass(element, 'translate-to-player-spot-1');
                })});
            },`

But I'm not sure how to use it - some guidance would be wonderful :)

Comment: I will take a look at it tomorrow morning and try to help as much as I can :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined` because in the following code `clickedCard` is not a DOM element:

```
$animate.addClass(clickedCard, "translate-to-player-spot-1", function () {
  alert('wooo!');
});
```

In your `link` function you have the following:

```
element.on('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.addClass(element, 'translate-to-player-spot-1');
  });
});
```

This will not work as expected.

Consider the following simplified example of the rendered HTML:

```
<player-hand-template>
  <card></card>
  <card></card>
  <card></card>
</player-hand-template>
```

The `element` passed to the `link` function will be `player-hand-template`, not a single card.

What you can do instead is the following:

Change your `ng-click` to the following: `ng-click="click(card, $event)"`

And in your controller:

```
$scope.click = function(card, event) {

  var clickedElement = event.currentTarget;
}
```

Now you have access to both the object representing the card and the associated DOM element and can for example do:

```
$scope.click = function(card, event) {

  if (card.hasMoved) return;

  card.hasMoved = true;

  var clickedElement = event.currentTarget;

  var promise = $animate.addClass(clickedElement, 'translate-to-player-spot-1');

  promise.then(function() {
    console.log('Done.');
  });
};
```

As you see above, in Angular 1.3, `$animate.addClass` does not take a callback function as an argument but instead returns a promise.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5Gf2ApyxEKgGQAs98IjG?p=preview

Note that in this case you could as well move the click logic into the `link` function. If you actually should move it or not is hard to say without seeing the full picture. Usually you use `controller` when you want to expose an API to other directives (since they can inject the controller), otherwise you use `link`.

Comment: thanks! I hate to ask but could you by chance provide a simple/representative link function as I am not familiar with it. I have so far learned Angular from Shaping up with Angular and they didn't go into detail on the link function and the reading I've done on it isn't very clear.

Comment: Just ask, it's no problem :) Here is a version using link: http://plnkr.co/edit/XN1D6QsHPHWSci5KmaFU?p=preview

Comment: it seems whatever I do to the "card" object in the promise doesn't update the through:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lhHRQKOaHXbPIu2P5XB9?p=preview

Essentially what I wanted to do im my own app was:
https://gist.github.com/omarmir/8a85a81e2755b7058166

Sorry to continually bother!

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mentation that you always need to use `$apply` in the callback functions passed to the `$animate`-promise if it contains Angular-specific code. It's hidden somewhere in the documentation and is very often and easily missed. Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/izfkmLgT3bsipdHRv6dl?p=preview And as I said, you can continue to ask, it's no problem :)

Comment: Note that when removing the element the css transition delay will be applied, so you probably want to separate the transform and transition into two different classes. Then you can remove the class with the transition from the element before removing the item and it should be removed without the delay.

Comment: Ah great advice and thanks again for the help! I'm sure I'll be back again with more questions but for now this is awesome :)

Comment: And I have to apologize again, I can't help it - I'm Canadian :)

Is there a different way to resolve promises when the animation isn't pure CSS - for example: http://plnkr.co/8kQkSB?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, not in the way you are trying in that example I think.

Comment: I'm reading the docs but they aren't exactly clear how and where the "done" function gets called. I also have a feeling that with JS animations I won't have access to my objects because the animation and the callback/promise will be in the animation service rather than the link/controller function. I'll keep trying to see if I can figure it out but if you get a chance to review and point me in the right direction that'd be great!

Comment: Got it :) - same concept - just had to run the calllback function:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kK0cm1ZSKO3m0IrV7oqy?p=preview

Man does it feel good to figure something out on your own! Thanks again for all your help.